# Código não atualiza no hibernate JPA no Eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Olá pessoal estou fazendo um sisteminha para afiar um pouco minhas técnicas e me deparei com um problema. Modifiquei um código meu a um tempinho mas quando fui depurar parecia que ele estava executando o código antigo. Estou fazendo um crud com Hibernate JPA e Eclipse. Se puderem me ajudar! Para facilitar o entendimento, esta parecendo que estou mexendo no meu codigo HTML e quando dou F5 no navegador não atualiza para o novo código!

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o teu código não está sendo atualizado no servidor de aplicação. Supondo que você está usando maven lipe o cache e refaça o pacote da aplicação com o seguinte comando:

```
mvn clean package
```

Caso prefira fazer tudo dentro da sua IDE basta procurar `"Limpar e Construir"` e depois reiniciar ou reimplantar seu servidor de aplicação.

Comment: Estou usando o Eclipse EE e não achei esta opção.

Comment: clica com o botão direito sobre o projeto, vai em `run as`, seleciona `maven clean` e depois `maven build`